# unable to install autotest in ubuntu environment

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to install autotest in ubuntu environment.

```
$ pip3 install autotest==0.16.4
```

After I execute I get the following error:

```
python3 -m pip install autotest==0.16.4
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting autotest==0.16.4
  Using cached autotest-0.16.4.tar.gz (11.3 MB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-cw5xzm8k/autotest/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-cw5xzm8k/autotest/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-8yy0dvmj
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-cw5xzm8k/autotest/
    Complete output (6 lines):
    usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
       or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
       or: setup.py --help-commands
       or: setup.py cmd --help
    
    error: invalid command 'egg_info'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

$ python3 --version
Python 3.7.8
$ pip -V
pip 20.1.1 from /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
sudo pip3 install autotest==0.16.4
```

The error is that it cannot write to destination, most probably due to permissions.

Comment: Shouldn't they try `pip3 install -U autotest==0.16.4` first, since `sudo` can do odd things with pip?

Comment: `Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable` suggests the destination is non-writable, using `-U` to upgrade would have the same effect and same error. Or he can use `--user` to try and install under his user space

Comment: Whoops, that's what I meant to write. Completely forgot the arguments for pip...

Comment: ran pip3 install --user autotest==0.16.4. get the same error: error: invalid command 'egg_info'

Comment: did you try with `sudo`?

Comment: You could've added the new output.. if egg_info is not found, try first `pip3 install -U setuptools`, and then run your initial command

Comment: After that, I land up in:    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/tmp/pip-build-nogikklw/autotest/setup.py", line 4, in <module>
        import autotest.common as common  # pylint: disable=W0611
    ImportError: No module named 'autotest' Ran with sudo

Comment: Are you running one command with sudo and the other without sudo?